# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter

Ive been trying to run the code of my colleague, changed all the needed directories names and stuff, but still getting some errors and i have not programmed in a long time, so I also cannot find the mistake so quickly.
[This is the error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTwsQ.png) and  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3mBn.png)

I dont have a readme how to run this code. I only know that they used conda + jupyter for creating this program. I am trying to run it on pycharm as im more familiar with it + its more comfortable for me. But i also think maybe here is the issue. I dont know.

I installed python, chose it as interpreter in pycharm, installed all the needed modules that need to be imported.

I am a little lost in all the directory matter though. Please help and ask questions if you need additional info

[image]

```
import sys
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math
import datetime
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import skew
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from numpy import nan
from collections import Counter
import re
import datetime
import glob
import warnings
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)

data = "...."
files = os.listdir(data)
print(files)
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(f, sep=',') for f in files)
# Join all the separate csvs in one dataframe
df_merged = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
df_merged
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) otherwise we can't help you. And do not include images of errors or images of code. See also [how to  ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it stands, your question is not specific enough to be directly answerable.

Comment: @syoung , i added the screen of the code that breaks.

Comment: Screenshots are not acceptable forms of code, always include text as text, not as images.

Comment: Yes, never do screenshots. But instead of stalling for the sake of etiquette, I'll point out that `....` is not a directory. It's as simple as that. Did you mean`../..`?

Comment: Please post the concrete One-Drive path - output from `print(data)`. May also read [OneDrive as Data Storage for Python Project | by Joe T. Santhanavanich | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/onedrive-as-data-storage-for-python-project-2ff8d2d3a0aa).